# JASPER REPORT: Subreport nightmare, datasource is List

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

Cannot view main report with subreport...

Main Java Class

```
   public class SubRepoExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
       SubRepoExample repo = new SubRepoExample();
       repo.combineMasterAndSubreport();
    }

     public void combineMasterAndSubreport() throws JRException{

         JasperReport main = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/subrepoexample/masterReport.jrxml");

        JasperReport sub = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/subrepoexample/subReport.jrxml");

        //create a list for holding the subreport object



        SubreportWrapper subDataWrap = new SubreportWrapper();

        List<SubreportObject> subData = subDataWrap.getSubData();

        Map para = new HashMap();
        //pass the report itself through a parameter
        para.put("SUBREPORT", sub);
        //pass the list to parameter
        para.put("subData",subData);


        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(main, para,new   JRTableModelDataSource(createMasterData()));
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);  

    }

      public DefaultTableModel createMasterData(){

        String [] cols = {"COL_1","COL_2","COL_3"};
        Object[][] data = {{"Data","Data","Data"},
                        {"Data","Data","Data"},                                  
                      };
         DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,cols);

    return dtm;}

}
```

SubreportObject class reponsible for creating subreport data which eventually is placed on a List.

```
 public class SubreportObject {
      String name;
      int age;

     public SubreportObject(String name,int age){
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;  
         }

     public String getName() {
     return name;
         }

     public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
         }

     public int getAge() {
     return age;
         }

     public void setAge(int age) {
     this.age = age;
         }

      }
```

Bean Factory Class

```
 public class SubreportWrapper {
    //String name;
    List<SubreportObject> subData;

//    public SubreportWrapper(List<SubreportObject> subData){
//        this.subData = subData;
//    }

    public List<SubreportObject> getSubData() {

        subData = new ArrayList();
        subData.add(new SubreportObject("Jane",20));
        subData.add(new SubreportObject("Mike",25));
        subData.add(new SubreportObject("Kev",20));
        return subData;
    }
    public void setSubData(List<SubreportObject> subData) {
        this.subData = subData;
    }  
  }
```

JRXML snippets both in Main jrxml and Subreport jrxml
[image: field declaration of a list both in main report and subreport]

Datasorce snippet through JRBeanCollection
[image: datasorce]
The SUBREPORT_DIR is in place

Error stacktrace
[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `JRBeanCollectionDatasource` constructor with subdata as field `$F{subData}`, use parameter instead: `$P{subData}`.

No need to pass subreport in `SUBREPORT` parameter since the .jasper file will be loaded based on `subreportExpression` and `SUBREPORT_DIR` parameter.

Comment: Thank you sir! You have helped a lot, Strangely though, as the report loads, i can see the Main Report Data but not the Subreport Data, no error stack trace whatsoever.

Comment: please help [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149597/jasper-reports-subeport-showing-null-values-in-main-report-datasource-is-a-jav)