# Jasper Reports: Subeport showing null values in Main Report, datasource is a java List

Tags: java, jasper-reports

**WHAT I HAVE**

My Main Report shows all values are null from my subreport.

[image]

**WHAT I WANT**
[image]

I am passing data to subReport from MainReport through a parameter called subData as shown in the MainReport JRXML snippet below.

**NB**: Its a List

[image]

My subReport snippet in the MainReport is given below, the dataSource expression is clearly "$P{subData}"

[image]

My main java class passes an instance of a List (named subData) through a parameter (named subDataOrion) shown below.

```
public class SubRepoExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
   SubRepoExample repo = new SubRepoExample();
   repo.combineMasterAndSubreport();
}

public void combineMasterAndSubreport() throws JRException{

    JasperReport main = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/subrepoexample/masterReport.jrxml");

    JasperReport sub = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/subrepoexample/subReport.jrxml");



   //create a list for holding the subreport object

    //SubreportWrapper subDataWrap = new SubreportWrapper();

    List<SubreportObject> subData = new ArrayList();
    //subData.add(subDataWrap.getSubData());
    subData.add(new SubreportObject("Kevin",20));
    subData.add(new SubreportObject("Jane",20));
    subData.add(new SubreportObject("Mike",20));
    subData.add(new SubreportObject("Simon",20)); 
    //subData.add(new SubreportObject("Naomi",25));
    //subData.add(new SubreportObject("Pat",20));


    //SubreportWrapper subDataWrap = new SubreportWrapper();

    //List<SubreportObject> subData = subDataWrap.getSubData();

    Map para = new HashMap();
    //pass the report itself through a parameter
    //para.put("SUBREPORT", sub);
    //pass the list to parameter
    //JRDataSource subx = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(subData);
    para.put("subDataOrion",subData);

    //JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sub, para,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(subData));      
    //JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(main, para,new JRTableModelDataSource(createMasterData()));


     JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
            "src/subrepoexample/subReport.jrxml", 
            "src/subrepoexample/subReport.jasper"); 


    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(main, para,new JRTableModelDataSource(createMasterData()));
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);  

}

 public DefaultTableModel createMasterData(){

    String [] cols = {"COL_1","COL_2","COL_3"};
    Object[][] data = {{"Data","Data","Data"},
                       {"Data","Data","Data"},       
                       {"Data","Data","Data"},   
                       {"Data","Data","Data"},   
                       {"Data","Data","Data"},  
                      };
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data,cols);

return dtm;}

}
```

SubReport class that creates the subReport objects

```
public class SubreportObject {
  String name;
  int age;

 public SubreportObject(String name,int age){
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;  
     }

 public String getName() {
 return name;
     }

 public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
     }

 public int getAge() {
 return age;
     }

 public void setAge(int age) {
 this.age = age;
     }

  }
```

I am aware there are two issues here, the **arrangement** issue of the data since the subreport data is mixed. or scrambled with the main report data as shown in the first screen shot. This I think can be fixed by groups, which is not my question here.

**MY QUESTION**:

I need first to eliminate the 'null' values so that I can go to the next stage of using group expression. Am stuck here and not sure what is wrong? At least I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103670/jasper-report-subreport-nightmare-datasource-is-list) and at least 'null' values appeared, earlier they were completely not appearing.

Why is the data in the List appearing as 'null', when compiled separately, they compile wonderfully.

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry for being sloppy on the earlier version of this question. Thank you people.

**EDIT 2:**

I have added the JRBeanCollection as shown below

[image: newCode]

Even changed the parameter class to JRDataSource as below

[image]

but still shows null values..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `JRBeanCollectionDatasource`, a List is not a datasource per se, unless it implements the JRDataSource interface should be wrapped/adapted by a JRDataSource.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the report is still showing null values.Please look at the **EDIT 2** above.

Comment: You are setting `subDataOrion` parameter in Java but you are declaring `subData` parameter in jrxml. And both must be the same in `dataSourceExpression`.

Comment: You r correct Sir! Although now its only the first row that is showing the data, the others r still null ,I think bundling the two in different groups may help to unscramble them. If there's a quick tip without use of groups i will appreciate. Thanks a million.

Comment: Grouping is not needed. Can you post the jrxml?

Comment: I cant post the JRXML, the copy function is disabled, but thanks for your help